# Do I need to use to after is?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I met such an sentence : "*All i want is to mess around*"
And I was wondering why there is **to** ? this is the rule or so it should be in English .Just where to appears, and somewhere in such sentences does not .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare

> All I want is to mess around.

and

> All I want is ice cream.

Both sentences have the form, "All I want is *X*." Consider that if the speaker were not specifying that *X* was the only thing she desired, she could have said "I want *X*." But shifting to the non-unique desire does not change the way that we express *X*," whether that be "ice cream" or "to mess around."

Comment: thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

[**Want** has to be followed by a complement.  The complement can be a noun or pronoun as an object, or a verb in the to-infinitive form, or an object plus a verb in the to-infinitive form.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/want)

So

> All I want is to mess around.

is the correct way to make this sentence.

The only answer for *why* we use the to-infinitive and not the bare infinitive is probably "Because that is the way English is."

Comment: I thought that by this rule we would use : "*All I want is to mess around.*".but here we have after want **is** . Or does *to* refer to want?

Comment: @Omegon  I'm not sure what your question is *"All I want is to mess around"*  **is** the correct form.  The *to* is part of "to mess around", if that is what you are asking.

Comment: I apologize if I don't explain it well and thank you for your help. I understand to infinitive after want "I want to eat". But I do not know if **is** is wedged between them (between want and to ) should something change or not ?

Comment: @Omegon  No, nothing changes.  You still use the to-infinitive.